# Problem While Installing Scid vs. PC

Tags: software-installation, compiling, tar, chess

I downloaded scid_vs_pc-4.18.1.tgz from here: http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net
unzipped with archive manager. opened terminal in folder called scid_vs_pc-4.18.1 , then entered ./configure and got this:

```
jonathan@livingstone ~/Downloads/scid_vs_pc-4.18.1 $ ./configure
Scid vs. PC configure - Makefile configuration program
Tcl/Tk version: 8.6
Your operating system is: Linux 4.13.0-26-generic
Location of "tcl.h": not found
Location of "tk.h": not found
Location of Tcl 8.6 library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
Location of Tk 8.6 library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
Location of X11 library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
Checking if your system already has zlib installed: yes.

Not all settings could be determined! See above for details.

The default Makefile was written.
You will need to edit it before you can compile Scid.
```

Then "make":

```
make
rm -f ./scid
cat tcl/start.tcl tcl/sharedir.tcl tcl/config.tcl tcl/bitmaps.tcl tcl/language.tcl tcl/utils.tcl tcl/utils/date.tcl tcl/utils/font.tcl tcl/utils/graph.tcl tcl/utils/history.tcl tcl/utils/pane.tcl tcl/utils/sound.tcl tcl/utils/string.tcl tcl/utils/tooltip.tcl tcl/utils/validate.tcl tcl/utils/win.tcl tcl/misc/misc.tcl tcl/htext.tcl tcl/file.tcl tcl/file/finder.tcl tcl/file/bookmark.tcl tcl/file/recent.tcl tcl/file/epd.tcl tcl/file/spellchk.tcl tcl/file/maint.tcl tcl/edit.tcl tcl/game.tcl tcl/game/browser.tcl tcl/windows.tcl tcl/windows/gamelist.tcl tcl/windows/pgn.tcl tcl/windows/book.tcl tcl/windows/comment.tcl tcl/windows/eco.tcl tcl/windows/stats.tcl tcl/windows/tree.tcl tcl/windows/crosstab.tcl tcl/windows/pfinder.tcl tcl/windows/tourney.tcl tcl/windows/switcher.tcl tcl/search/search.tcl tcl/search/board.tcl tcl/search/header.tcl tcl/search/material.tcl tcl/contrib/ezsmtp/ezsmtp.tcl tcl/tools/email.tcl tcl/tools/import.tcl tcl/tools/optable.tcl tcl/tools/preport.tcl tcl/tools/pinfo.tcl tcl/tools/analysis.tcl tcl/tools/comp.tcl tcl/tools/wbdetect.tcl tcl/tools/reper.tcl tcl/tools/graphs.tcl tcl/tools/tablebase.tcl tcl/tools/ptracker.tcl tcl/help/help.tcl tcl/help/tips.tcl tcl/menus.tcl tcl/board.tcl tcl/move.tcl tcl/main.tcl tcl/tools/correspondence.tcl tcl/lang/english.tcl tcl/dnd/tkdnd.tcl tcl/dnd/tkdnd_unix.tcl tcl/tools/fics.tcl tcl/tools/uci.tcl tcl/end.tcl tcl/tools/tacgame.tcl tcl/tools/sergame.tcl tcl/tools/calvar.tcl tcl/tools/tactics.tcl tcl/tools/novag.tcl tcl/misc/flags.tcl tcl/tools/inputengine.tcl > ./scid
chmod +x scid
cp scripts/sc_addmove.tcl ./sc_addmove
chmod +x sc_addmove
cp scripts/sc_epgn.tcl ./sc_epgn
chmod +x sc_epgn
cp scripts/sc_spell.tcl ./sc_spell
chmod +x sc_spell
cp scripts/sc_eco.tcl ./sc_eco
chmod +x sc_eco
cp scripts/sc_import.tcl ./sc_import
chmod +x sc_import
cp scripts/sc_remote.tk ./sc_remote
chmod +x sc_remote
cp scripts/sc_tree.tcl ./sc_tree
chmod +x sc_tree
cp scripts/scidpgn.tcl ./scidpgn
chmod +x scidpgn
cp scripts/pgnfix.py ./pgnfix
chmod +x pgnfix
cp scripts/spliteco.tcl ./spliteco
chmod +x spliteco
g++ -fno-rtti -O2 -fno-exceptions -Wall   -I/usr/include -o src/pgnscid.o -c src/pgnscid.cpp
src/pgnscid.cpp:30:17: fatal error: tcl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:422: recipe for target 'src/pgnscid.o' failed
make: *** [src/pgnscid.o] Error 1
```

there is a fatal error on line 4 from the last line `src/pgnscid.cpp:30:17: fatal error: tcl.h: No such file or directory`

then I entered sudo make install and got this:

```
jonathan@livingstone ~/Downloads/scid_vs_pc-4.18.1 $ sudo make install
[sudo] password for jonathan: 
g++ -fno-rtti -O2 -fno-exceptions -Wall   -I/usr/include -o src/pgnscid.o -c src/pgnscid.cpp
src/pgnscid.cpp:30:17: fatal error: tcl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:422: recipe for target 'src/pgnscid.o' failed
make: *** [src/pgnscid.o] Error 1
```

**How can i properly install Scid vs. PC? Where is the main problem and how to solve it... Thank you.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved! I installed ths packages

```
sudo apt-get install tcl8.6-dev tcl8.6
sudo apt-get install tk8.6-dev tk8.6 libgcj15-dev
```

Then

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
scid
```

And it works! ^_^